# php writing to files and folders

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Just finished developing a website for a client and I've uploaded it to their VPS, but we're having problems with php/wordpress writing to files and folders. I haven't had a problem like this in many years because I'm used to having suhosin installed. I can chmod to 777, but I believe that is a security risk? As far as I know the other option is to change the owner of the files/folders to the same user as apache (nobody). I tried to do that but I don't have permission.

So my questions are:
Is chmod 777 a security risk?
is getting the server admin to change the owner to match the apache user a good solution?
Or what is the best solution?

Comment: `chown nobody:nobody` does not work for you ?

Comment: I am not root user, so no it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I do it by changing the folder(s) owner to be the same as apache user. I find it better than chmod to 777.

Using chmod 777 enables full access for all and is clearly undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress normally only need the upload folder (and maybe the config.php) to be writable as far as I can remember. Like Khaled said I would not put 777 but change the upload folder group to apache group and give the group write access. I do not recommend to put the whole wordpress installation writatable but only what you need.

```
chgrp <apache_group> /path/to/folder

chmod g+rwx /path/to/folder
```